# scale_fill_identity with custom fill colors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I tough I solved the problem with the geo_map fill color is aes (see this post [fill color in world map using geo_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901964/how-to-plot-correct-colors-in-r-maps-library))...

But I am stuck again with it, now with a different regional map that I build from shp files and simplified to a csv file (available here: [mapNUTSIII.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/112525/mapaNUTSIIIs.csv)). I have a data file with colors to plot in the map (available here: [data.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/112525/data.csv))

This my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Read map
map <- read.csv("C:/Temp/mapaNUTSIIIs.csv", sep=";")
# Read file with colors to plot
datacor <- read.csv("C:/Temp/data.csv", sep=";")

# Make map from mapaNUTSIII.csv
prtnutsiii <- ggplot()+
geom_polygon(data = map, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill="gray97", colour="black", size=0.25)+
coord_quickmap()
prtnutsiii

# Make map with colors defined by datacor$cor
prtcor <- prtnutsiii +
geom_map(data = datacor, map = map, aes(map_id = id, fill=cor), colour="darkgray", size = 0.25) +
scale_fill_identity("Color regions", labels = c("<475","]475; 500]", "]500;525]","]525; 550]", ">550"), breaks = c("red4", "red", "yellow", "green", "green4"), guide = "legend") +
theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.key.size = unit(0.4,"cm"))
prtcor
```

The `scale_fill_identity` supposedly plots the colors in `datacor$cor`. But it does not and I don't know why... This is the graph with colors:

[image: Portugal Map]

Any idea is welcome on how to solve/explain this is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: As there is only one "green" row in datacor, that seems like a good place to start any troubleshooting.  If you map just the id with green fill, which has the id of "REGIÃO DE LEIRIA", the result seems to look the same as what is filled in green in your plot.  Could there be mistakes in "datacor"?

Comment: Thanks aosmith.  I couldn't follow your rationale.  The "REGIÃO DE LEIRIA"  is indeed the only green we should get.  That region,  painted in yellow, is above the one that is painted in green  "ÁREA METROPOLITANA DE LISBOA".  My point is why isn't the `fill=cor` returning the correct colors in datacor$cor?....

Comment: No.  "ÁREA METROPOLITANA DE LISBOA"  should be yellow in the map,  not green.  The green region in the map is the "ÁREA METROPOLITANA DE LISBOA"  but in the `data$cor` is yellow.  So R is not plotting the colors in `cor`.  Same happens to other regions in the map :-(

Comment: Ah, that goes back to my first point, then.  Plot just "REGIÃO DE LEIRIA".  Like `geom_polygon(data = subset(map, id == "REGIÃO DE LEIRIA"), aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill="gray97", colour="black", size=0.25)`.  When I did that, I was surprised to see that the resulting polygon looked exactly like the green-filled polygon in your original plot.  If that is supposed to be  "ÁREA METROPOLITANA DE LISBOA" then something is wrong.

Comment: Oh I see.  Maybe a problem with the `id` in the mapNUTSIIIs.csv file?

Comment: I guess I have to review the name of all my polygons... because somehow they are not attributed correctly. Thanks aosmith!